# How to handle the back press button in Android without hitting the network again

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two screens included in my app. I am returning a list of ads after parsing xml and making an api call. Then whenever I click on a recyclerView Item another activity is displayed showing more data about the clicked item. Whenever I press the back button, a new api call is issued. So how to prevent that?

Any Suggestion?

Here is my Main Activity:

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // Setting the adapter and the recycler view

        loadPage();



    }
    public void loadPage() {
        new DownloadXmlTask().execute(URL);
    }

    private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<AdEntry>> {
        @Override
        protected List<AdEntry> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<AdEntry> adEntries) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Processed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mAdsAdapter.setAdData(adEntries);
            entryList = adEntries;
            super.onPostExecute(adEntries);
        }
    }


    public List<AdEntry> loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
            entryList = parse(stream);
        } finally {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.close();
        }
        return entryList;
    }

    public InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
         // Open HttpURLConnection
        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
      //Some code
    }
```

Comment: paste your code to better understand

Comment: I just want to know how to handle the press of the back button so that no api call issued again. So what should the method look like?

Comment: Can you share a pseudo code of this scenario please

Comment: @Laura I've deleted my old comment as I think it will be a better approach to use SharedPreference instead. So you'll create a sharedPreference when you get into Activity A and set a boolean value to false (if value false - do not make API call) > when in Activity B - you'll get sharedPreference, get boolean value and set that to true. That should hopefully allow you to determine if the user has been to activity B. Let me know if this still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe you use onResume method for calling your API from the first activity? Check that

Comment: @Nero I updated the main activity. Now how can i go from here

Comment: send local broadcast or interface on back press so you should know its come from second activity and you can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

In which lifecycle method are you making your api call?
**onCreate** for example would be the method in which you could make your api call, that method is only called once in the activity's lifecycle (i.e. when your activity is created or recreated)
**onStart** and **onResume** will be called when your activity becomes visible again, I guess this is what's happening in your case.

Handling the back press can be done by overriding **onBackPressed**, but that won't help much with your problem without writing quite a bit of code that isn't necessary.

So, try to make your api call in **onCreate**.

Comment: how should I implement the onBackPressed() as I made the api call in onCreate().

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to store the data of the list in onSavedInstanceState() if thats applicable?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling your api in a right place.
I guess that the problem is finishing the mainActivity and then go to second activity.
so if you need to use the back button and come back to the mainActivity, you don't have to finish the mainActivity and by this approach the onCreate will not trigger again.
and check the activity lifecycle here [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: Then how to implement this(you don't have to finish the mainActivity and by this approach the onCreate will not trigger again) in my code. Any recommendation?

Comment: when you are navigating to the second activity, don't call finish .
if you call finish, you need to recreate the first activity which is redundant, if you don't call the finish, first activity will be exist in the back stack and when you click back in the second activity, the back stack will handle it automatically and navigate to the first activity

Comment: and then in the second activity you just need to call `super.onBackPressed();`

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you check first how the Android lifecycle works (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). It will help you decide where to call the API in the first place (**onCreate** could be the place to do this)

When you return to a previous activity, it will most commonly invoke the **onResume** method.

You might also want to consider saving the state of the activity, removing the necessity to call the API again, or consider a Cache to avoid calling the API multiple times.

== UPDATE ==

A. Change the launch mode of your app to be a Single Instance

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

B. Configure your adapter and view in the onCreate. Initiate the task, etc etc

```
package com.example.mylist

import // ... all your imports

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BookLoadingTaskDelegate {
    private var listView: ListView? = null
    private var data: MutableList<Book> = mutableListOf()
    private lateinit var adapter: BooksAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        this.listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
        this.adapter = BooksAdapter(this, data)

        loadNetworkIntensiveData()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        this.listView!!.adapter = this.adapter
    }

    private fun loadNetworkIntensiveData() {
        LoadingTask(this).execute()
    }

    override fun processResult(result: List<Book>?) {
        Log.d("ProcessResult", "Found ${result?.size}")

        this.listView!!.post {
            data.addAll(result!!)
            Log.d("ProcessResult", "Found data elements: *${data.size}")
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        this.listView!!.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }


    class LoadingTask(private val delegate: BookLoadingTaskDelegate) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Book>>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): List<Book> {
            Log.w("Background task", "Loading heavy stuff in the background")

            val tempList: MutableList<Book> = mutableListOf()

            // ... Load data into the list

            return tempList
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: List<Book>?) {
            delegate.processResult(result)
        }
    }

    data class Book(
        val title: String,
        val summary: String
    )

    class BooksAdapter(private val context: Context, private val data: List<Book>) : BaseAdapter() {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            Log.d("GetView", "Retrieving element at position $position")

            val book = getItem(position) as Book

            var v = //... do what you need to do to populate the view

            return v
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            Log.d("Adapter - Get Count", "Size: ${data.size}")
            return data.size
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? {
            return if (position > data.size) null else data[position]
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }
    }

}

interface BookLoadingTaskDelegate {
    fun processResult(result: List<MainActivity.Book>?)
}
```

Comment: Normally, when you navigate from ActivityA to ActivityB, the state of the original ActivityA is kept, unless the activity is explicitly "finished", in which case the onCreate is re-invoked (or after a long period of time). So when you go "back" to ActivityA, the state is restored (though you'll enter in the **onResume**, not the **onCreate**). If you want to keep the data, fetch from a remote API, store it as a member in the ActivityA or in a Cache.

Comment: All what I want is that whenever I press the back button from the second activity to go back to the list in main activity, to not make again an api call. Can please write me a pseudo code of how to implement your scenario?